# Access a Multiple level stdClass object field?

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap, stdclass

I have received this ridiculously complex array of objects as a SOAP response. I need to print out the "string_operator_collection" using a loop. It is a collection of operators similiar to ["equal_wild"] but with all different names. The nesting is so deep that I can't seem to access using normal methods. Any ideas please?

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { 
["get_search_frame_details_response"]
=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { 
    ["response_context"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) { 
        ["session_token"]
        => string(28) "b0ac045931183d1ead6b9f6da061" 
        ["response_status"]=> string(2) "OK" 
        ["response_message"]=> string(0) "" } 
            ["search_frame_details_response_data"]
            => object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
                ["search_field_collection"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1) { 
                    ["search_field"]=> array(4) { 
                    [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (3) { 
                        ["field_id"]
                        => string(82) 
                        "OsCashAllocationCashAllocationPk" 
                        ["field_name"]=> string(15) "Customer Number" 
                        ["field_operator"]
                        => object(stdClass)#8 (1) { 
                            ["string_operator_collection"]
                            => object(stdClass)#9 (16) { 
                                ["equal_wild"]=> string(2) "=*"
```

My best effort so far is:

```
get_search_frame_details_response->
  search_frame_details_response_data->
    search_field_collection->search_field;

    print_r(array_values($search_frame_op1));
```

Comment: Of cource you can use `normal methods`!!!! You just need to spend some time working it out

Comment: I personally find a `print_r()` output easier to follow, try that, post it if you still cannot work it out

Comment: The indentation it's posted with here is wild. It makes it very difficult to parse visually. If you are dumping this in the browser with `var_dump()`, view the page source and copy it exactly as it appears there.  `print_r()` will be a little less noisy and easier to read too.

Comment: Sorry I had to format it to fit in with the Stack Overflow rules. @RiggsFolly I have tried print_r and it is clearer. I have tried so many different combinations for hours already.

Comment: Like I said, really hard to tell with this indentation, but it looks like `$var->get_search_frame_details_response->search_frame_details_response_data->search_field_collection->search_field[0]->field_operator->string_operator_collection->equal_wild`  Build that up incrementally and `print_r()` each step along the way to make sure you're narrowing it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I have added an edit to show the only combination that's not producing null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (display is not helpful) the address of `string_operator_collection` is

```
$obj
->get_search_frame_details_response
->search_frame_details_response_data
->search_field_collection
->search_field[]
->field_operator
->string_operator_collection
->equal_wild
```

So as the array starts at

```
$obj
->get_search_frame_details_response
->search_frame_details_response_data
->search_field_collection
->search_field[];
```

we can write a loop like this

```
$the_array =  $obj
                ->get_search_frame_details_response
                ->search_frame_details_response_data
                ->search_field_collection
                ->search_field;  

foreach($the_array as $field ) {
    echo $field
            ->field_operator
            ->string_operator_collection
            ->equal_wild;
}
```

Comment: I will try to format as nicely as you in future. Your answer is brilliant. Do you do any consulting? Top answer.

Comment: @RobertMorel If you are asking if I can be employed on a temporary basis the answer is YES

Comment: Awesome, I will wait to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

Using loop:

```
function findInCollection($collection, $fieldToFind){
    foreach($collection as $key => $subCollection) {
        if ($key == $fieldToFind) {
            return $subCollection;
        }

        if ( ! is_object($subCollection)) {
            return null;
        }

        return findInCollection($subCollection, $fieldToFind);
    }
}
```

But **remember** that you may have really hard issues if key dose no exists.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really working too well in this particular case.